# How to add new line in docx file generation using DOCX4J

Tags: newline

I have prepared the WordprocessingMLPackage with the values. I have a string value with the new line break. I have to generate a word report as a zip file.

The String value is replaced as it is in the word template, without the line breaks.

I have tried to replace the `\n` line breaks in the string with the w:br but it doesn't help.

Any other ways to do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot replace the text like that alone, you need to insert each line separately.

You need to do something like that:

Before replace:

```
<w:p>
    <w:r>
        <w:t>MY_PLACEHOLDER</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
```

After replace:

```
<w:p>
    <w:r>
        <w:t>Beforeline break</w:t>
        <w:br/>
        <w:t>After line break</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
```

To achieve that, you need the enclosing Element (in this case Run-Element). On this element you can do `getContent()`. That is a list, which contains the `<w:t>` text element, and you can remove and add other elements.

I did it like this:

```
     Text text; //Text object where the substitution should take place
     Run run; // Run object that encloses the Placeholder (parent of text)
     List<String> dataLines; //List of Lines to be inserted

     // ...
     // some code to
     // * get the Text object where the substitution should take place
     // * get Run object (which can be cast to ContentAccessor)
     // * get List of to be inserted values

     //get list of content of run element (in the example it will be the text object with value MY_PLACEHOLDER)
     List<Object> content = ((ContentAccessor) run).getContent();

     //go through the content that needs to be inserted
     for (int i = 0; i < dataLines.size(); i++)
     {
        if (i == 0)
        {
           // if it is the first line, replace MY_PLACEHOLDER with the first line
           text.setValue(dataLines.get(i));
        }
        else
        {
           // else add line breaks and other text elements
           Br lineBreak = new Br();
           content.add(lineBreak);

           Text t2 = (Text) XmlUtils.deepCopy(text);
           t2.setValue(dataLines.get(i));

           //content can also be added at an index if necessary (otherwise they are added at the end)
           content.add(t2);
        }
     }
```

You can also remove the text element and add all others. Hope this gives an idea, what needs to be done.